# namespacing or otherwise separating Bootstrap styles?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 3 CSS is typically used site-wide or application-wide. Knowing this, I designed a tool that HAPPENS to use Bootstrap in a sample application. This is after going through requirements processes. The explicit design was "It happens to use Bootstrap in this example, but the target user would likely provide their own styling rules."

However, the results looked great and the powers that be have asked, "can this tool be included on any arbitrary page and still look like this?"

The short answer of course is "no". Bootstrap's styles do all kinds of things like using `border-sizing: border-box` on a wildcard (*) selector. This is going to mess with people's existing CSS if it's not already built on Bootstrap.

---

Is there a way to encapsulate Bootstrap styles so that they're restricted only within that particular tool/widget? So in the div `<div class="bootstrappy">`, everything is affected by Bootstrap classes and outside of there, nothing is? The goal is to be able to include my Bootstrap-styled widget on a page that didn't previously include Bootstrap, without modifying what was there previously.

It's OK if I have to do this as part of a build process (I am using Grunt right now, so that'd be the best option for me); what I'm looking to avoid is manually combing through Bootstrap in order to cull or modify element-level rules so that they don't stomp over a whole page.

Comment: Hmm, this is an interesting issue. First thought that comes to my mind is using an `<iframe>` that contains your tool. I've been able to include Bootstrap widgets on a CRM homepage that isn't built with Bootstrap, but they are self-contained frames, and not directly part of the homepage's HTML.

Comment: Good thinking, Tim. I will propose the iframe idea. Still curious for non-iframe solutions if anyone out there has one!

Comment: Cool solution for this would be `scoped` attr https://jsfiddle.net/ajk3cgz8/ but it only works on firefox http://caniuse.com/#search=scoped